# System.StackOverflowException when trying to reference SASxport library

Tags: r.net

I am trying to use RDotNet to create a SAS v5 transport file, my script runs fine in R but when I try to reference the library via the RDotNet `engine.Evaluate("library(SASxport)")` I get a `System.StackOverflowException`.

This is not happening for other libraries.

Comment: Can you post sample data that causes the problem?

Comment: I haven't put any data in, just initialized the engine and tried to reference the SASXport library#